# Simplifying $(\sin a + \tan a)(1 - \sin a)$

Tags: trigonometry

How do I simplify  $(\sin a + \tan a)(1 - \sin a)$?

After multiplying I get $$\sin a + \sin^2 a + \tan a - \tan a \sin a
 = \sin a + \sin^2 a + \frac{\sin a} {\cos a} - \frac{sin^2 a}  {cos a}$$

Thanks.

Comment: what exactly do you want?

Answer (score 0):

we have $$\left(\sin(a)+\frac{\sin(a)}{\cos(a)}\right)(1-\sin(a))=\frac{\sin(a)(1-\sin(a))(1+\cos(a))}{\cos(a)}$$

Comment: The answer choices for the given expression are - sin a, sec a, cosec a and cos a

Comment: The answer is cos a (arrived at by substituting 45 in place of a), but I would like to know the steps to arrive at this answer

Comment: what is $$45$$ a real or a complex number?

Comment: A real number.  The question does not specify whether 'a' is real, or complex, so I substituted a real number and arrived at the answer

Comment: or is this $$45^{\circ}$$? this makes sense

Comment: Yes, that makes more sense.